# Custom HTTP headers with XmlRpcClient

Tags: java, web-services, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I was wondering if anyone knows how to send custom HTTP headers using an XmlRpcClient in Java?

I see a custom header can be set using XmlRpcHttpTransport.setRequestHeader() but I don't see a way of tying this in with the XmlRpcClient itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Encountered the same problem and solved it by implementing XmlRpcTransport and overriding initHttpHeaders method. Here is an example:
http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-http-headers-with-xmlrpcclient.html